# How does hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create() get invoked?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I've been working with Drupal Console creating custom entity types as well as a custom module which should interface with this entity type. My situation is that I need the hook "hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create()" to be called somehow (I assume it gets called when the entity is created by default).

I guess I must implement this hook in some file, but I'm unsure of which file I should be implementing this hook in.

My module file structure is as follows (generated by Drupal Console)

[image: Drupal Module Structure]

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do something to your event entity (or some other entity you create in the module) or alter an entity from another source like core or a contrib module?

Comment: @acrosman It's an event entity that I generated with Drupal Console (drupal generate:entity:content)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create()` in your .module file, but since you noted in your comment that you are trying to react to the saving of the Event entity in your module, you are probably better served by overriding the `save()` method on the Event entity itself (I believe console gives you a stub method by default).

Comment: Would you be able to give the same answer but for a Drupal 8 module please?

Comment: @Martin Joiner: that is a Drupal 8 answer.  Is there some detail that would be helpful to add?

Comment: My mistake. At the time of writing I thought .module files were dropped when moving from 7 to 8.  Another question though, is ENTITY_TYPE the same as custom content type? So if I have a custom content type with the machine name `sausage` would the function be named `modulename_sausage_create()`?

Comment: The entity type is more general. It can be things like: node, user, taxonomy, etc. It sounds like in your context going to be a node (mymodule_node_create()), and you will need to check the node type within your function. The OP was creating a custom entity type instead of a custom node type.